# How do I properly call my init function in a Swift Struct?

Tags: swift, xcode

My current code is designed to make a Sha-256 hash for a crypto wallet key, and then print it to me so that I can confirm that it worked properly. Here's my code. By the way, I am a beginner, I still have much to learn.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct dataManager {
    let characterArray = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","f"]
      @State private var privKey = "0x"
    
        init() {
            for _ in 1...64 {
            privKey += characterArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(16))]
        
            print(privKey)
        }
        
    }

}
```

The issue is the fact that the init function never seems to be called, so I don't get anything printed to the console. I tried dividing by zero to see if there was a crash, and there wasn't one, which leads me to believe that it wasn't called or something along those lines.

EDIT: I should add that if I try to use the for loop outside of init, I just get an "expected declaration" error. I did some research and I thought that init was what I was supposed to use in a situation like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you expect `init` to be called? Do you *call* it anywhere?

Comment: Save `@State` variables for Views only, they shouldn't be used in normal structs. That is probably your issue. Structs aren't suppose to mutate, unless you call a mutating func. What would you like to accomplish?

Comment: @HunterLion, the State variable is just because I would like to be able to access that variable from a binding in a different struct. My end result honestly at the moment is to just be able to print "privKey". If I use the for in loop outside the init function I get an error that says "expected declaration", that's why I'm using init, as I assumed that's how I'm supposed to use it.

Comment: @Sweeper, I just want init to be called because If I use the for in loop outside of init, I just get an error stating "expected declaration", I did some research and found that I probably should be using init, which I though was called automatically.

Comment: "at the moment is to just be able to print 'privKey'" Well if you just want to do that, just do it with the `.onAppear { ... }` view modifier. You can put that loop in the braces. Though for experimenting with things like this, I would recommend using a playground, rather than a SwiftUI app.

Comment: @Sweeper, I don't have any views to add that modifier too. It's just a plain old struct without any views or anything like that. Playground might be my best bet, but I still want to know how to properly initialize things within a struct.

Comment: Well, if that's what you want then go read the [Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, `@State` is only for use within a SwiftUI `View`.

There are a couple of other minor errors, like leaving out `"e"` in your array.

Here's a working version of your code, modified as little as possible:

```
struct DataManager {
    let characterArray = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"]
    var privKey = "0x"
    
    init() {
        for _ in 1...64 {
            privKey += characterArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(16))]
            print(privKey)
        }
    }
}

let manager = DataManager()
print(manager.privKey)
```

Note that you could further refactor this. Here's another iteration that is a little Swift-ier in nature:

```
struct DataManager {
    let characterArray = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"]
    var privKey = "0x"
    
    init() {
        privKey += (1...64).map { _ in characterArray.randomElement()! }.joined()
    }
}
```

Or:

```
struct DataManager {
    var privKey = "0x" + (1...64).map { _ in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"].randomElement()! }.joined()
}
```

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question?

Comment: Yes, for the most part it did! Sorry for not getting back to you sooner, I wasn't doing any coding over the weekend and I had partially forgotten about it. Thanks for taking the time to give me a detailed easy to understand answer. It seems that it answers everything except for, why do I get an error after trying to print "privKey"? The error states "Expressions are not allowed at the top level". I don't have anything to initialize the print statement, but putting it under the for loop doesn't seem to run it.

Comment: In my example, I could use `print` at the top level because I was running it in a Playground. If you’re in an app, you can’t do that. “Putting it under the for loop doesn’t seem to run it” — it should, but I’d have to see exactly what you tried to see what went wrong.